# How to load data from external json file using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

This is my app.js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/db.json", function (data) {

        $(data.as).each(function (index, value) {

            console.log(value);
        });
    });
});
```

and this is db.json file

```
{
  "as": [
    {
      "imageID": "1",
      "imageSource": "Popular Science 1",
      "alt": "Science 1"
    },
    {
      "imageID": "2",
      "imageSource": "Popular Science 2",
      "alt": "Science 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to get only, for example, `Popular Science 2`?
if I write `console.log(value[1]);`, an error is displayed. How to index an array?

Comment: In JavaScript and most programming languages, arrays are accessed by zero based indices. [0] for the first item, [1] for the second, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
value.imageSource
```

as `value` is the object here.

```js
const data = {as:[{imageID:"1",imageSource:"Popular Science 1",alt:"Science 1"},{imageID:"2",imageSource:"Popular Science 2",alt:"Science 2"}]};

$(data.as).each(function(index, value) {
  console.log(value.imageSource);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you only want `Popular Science 2`, then there is no need to loop. You can simply do:

```js
const data = {as:[{imageID:"1",imageSource:"Popular Science 1",alt:"Science 1"},{imageID:"2",imageSource:"Popular Science 2",alt:"Science 2"}]};

console.log( data.as[1].imageSource );
```

Or, with some validation like:

```js
const data = {as:[{imageID:"1",imageSource:"Popular Science 1",alt:"Science 1"},{imageID:"2",imageSource:"Popular Science 2",alt:"Science 2"}]};

// Vlidating that we actually have an array and data as index 1
if( data && data.as && data.as.length > 1){ 
  console.log( data.as[1].imageSource );
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I only want to show 'Popular Science 2'? How?

Comment: You can use `console.log( data.as[1].imageSource );` or `console.log( data?.as[1]?.imageSource );`